# How would I create a select box inside a div without the dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to create a select box but I don't want it to be a drop down. I'm sorta new to react in some forms.

Picture is attached of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Comment: Isn't really enough detail here, but maybe you are looking for the attribute `multiple=true` ? Then if you set the height large enough it should get rid of the scroll bar

Comment: Yea, I added multiple and worked how I needed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be straight forward to do the following:

Add css:

```css
select {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Then make sure you use multiple="true" on the select

```
<select multiple="true" size="5">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

No need for react really